# Fool image hit counter - HackIT challenge

Tags: php, system-administration

I'm doing some HackIT challenges and I'm stuck as I'm really poor with PHP. The challenge is here: https://www.0xf.at/play/31.

There's a PHP script which creates a .jpg. That .jpg tracks the number of times it was hit with different IPs. I need 50 IPs to proceed with the challenge. So I could go the easy way and just post the link on some board but I'm wondering if there's an efficient technical way of solving this rather then just iterating through proxies. Maybe directly interacting with the PHP script?

Comment: > Post the image on stackoverflow > Do read the question to 50 people > Profit!

Comment: https://www.0xf.at/data/imgs/46d39e5979be3f45679ec916025c4a9b.jpg

Comment: I specificialy chose NOT to do so, as it's uninteresting and boring. There just has to be a technical solution, otherwise it wouldn't be a hackit challenge.

Comment: Use a web scraping online - you can hit 50 visit in a few minute. Or use TOR

Comment: spoof your ip or find some proxies to go through?  I've never spoofed my IP but I've heard it's relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

> To solve this level the image has to be accessed by 50 unique IP addresses

This is a lie.

They are counted only the first hit *per session*. So, all you need to do is open another browser with the cookie disabled, and refresh the image until you get 50 hit. Or open the console and run

```
watch curl https://www.0xf.at/data/imgs/your_hash.jpg
```

Comment: I finally have enough credit to tell you that I fixed the bug that made it possible to use the curl thing. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to post a comment (stupid stack overflow) but I'm the creator of the site and I now fixed the bug, stated by [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711206/federico) where you could just curl it. I had the local session variable in the ip counter therefore it wouldn't count if the accessing device/program had no session.

Now it works as stated in the description of the level